# Footer is overlapping website content

Tags: html, footer

I'm running a Drupal site and currently having issues with the current footer, I'm trying to figure out why it's constantly overlapping the entire site, I've been able to find out that color of the footer is the issue, I've tried changing the color, the same issue happens. I've tried putting a div tag before the footer and a horizontal line before the footer.

Below I've attached the code the footer is a responsive site, the main purpose of the footer was to have it able to run on mobile and desktop just haven't been able to get this last issue to be resolved. Each section contains a title of each feature including in the

The first section is the style sheet at the very top contains the form height and width. the footer colors are labeled as ct-footer this only includes the tag for each section such as ct-footer background or ct-footer pre for forms and div.

```css
html,
body,
img,
figure {
  max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #000;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.ct-u-paddingTop10 {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.ct-footer {
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.ct-footer-pre {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.ct-footer-pre span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.ct-footer-pre .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.ct-footer-pre .form-group:before,
.ct-footer-pre .form-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.ct-footer-pre .form-group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
  border: 1px solid #39a2bf;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0
}

.ct-footer-list {
  padding: 50px 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.ct-footer-list>li .ct-footer-list-header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #3a98b2;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.ct-footer-list>li ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.ct-footer-list>li ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.ct-footer-list>li ul li a:hover,
.ct-footer-post a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.ct-footer-post {
  background: #000;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.ct-footer-post .inner-left,
.ct-footer-post .inner-right {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.ct-footer-post ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}

.ct-footer-post ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.ct-footer-post a {
  color: #fff;
}

.ct-footer-post p {
  color: #fff;
}

.ct-footer-meta {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.ct-footer-meta .ct-socials {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.ct-footer-meta .ct-socials li {
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.ct-footer--with-button {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

address {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

address span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

address a {
  color: #fff;
}

address a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 12px 30px;
}

.btn.btn-motive {
  background-color: #00bff3;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn.btn-motive:hover,
.btn.btn-motive:hover:active {
  background-color: #00bff3;
}

.btn.btn-violet {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4f4f99;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn.btn-violet:hover {
  background-color: #37376b;
}

.btn.btn-violet:hover:active {
  background-color: #2f2f5b
}

.btn.btn-green {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #43670f;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #36520c;
}

.btn.btn-green:hover:active {
  background-color: #314a0b;
}

.btn.btn-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da2229;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn.btn-red:hover {
  background-color: #ae1b21;
}

.btn.btn-red:hover:active {
  background-color: #9d181e
}

.btn.btn-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.btn.btn-white:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.btn.btn-white:hover:active {
  background-color: #c9c9c9
}

.btn.btn-large {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: normal;
}

.ct-mediaSection {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.ct-section_header--type1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 115px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ct-section_header--type2 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: .7;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  left: -12px;
}

.ct-section_header--type2 span {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 115px;
  line-height: .8;
}

.ct-section_header--type2 img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}

.ct-section_header--type3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ct-section_header--type3 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("/core/fileparse.php/16/urlt/../images/ribbon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block
}

.ct-section_header--type3 span {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 150px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: .85
}

.ct-section_header--type4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ct-section_header--type4:before,
.ct-section_header--type4:after {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.ct-section_header--type4:after {
  clear: both
}

.ct-section_header--type4 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block
}

.ct-section_header--type4 span {
  font-family: 'nimbus-sans-condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  line-height: .7
}

.ct-section_header+p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ct-section_header--type4+p {
  font-family: 'nimbus-sans-condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .ct-footer-pre {
    display: table;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre>.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .ct-footer-list>li {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .ct-footer-list>li:last-child {
    width: 7%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1199px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group {
    padding-top: 15px
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .ct-footer-list>li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .ct-footer-post .inner-left {
    float: left;
  }
  .ct-footer-post .inner-right {
    float: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  .ct-footer-post {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .ct-footer-list>li {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .ct-footer-post p {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ct-footer-post p+p {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  address {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:767px) {
  .ct-footer-list>li {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
    top: -1px;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
    width: 331px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:479px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .ct-footer-list>li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .ct-footer-list {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .btn.btn-large {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    line-height: .9;
    font-size: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -.2px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: .8;
  }
  .ct-section_header+p {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type3 small {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4 small {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type3 span {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4 span {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4+p {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="ct-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="contentForm">&nbsp;</form>

    <ul class="ct-footer-list text-center-sm">
      <li>
        <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Contract Vehicles</h2>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Services</h2>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sales</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">About us</h2>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Thought Leadership</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Webinars</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sponsorships</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Advisors</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Training Program</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Activities &amp; Campaigns</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Resources&nbsp;</h2>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="">WebCorpCo Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Hackathons</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="">News Releases</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Newsletters</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Our Board</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Our Staff</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="ct-footer-meta text-center-sm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img alt="logo" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/logo.png" /></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <address><span>WebCorpCo</span><br />
123 Easy Street<br />
Orlando, Florida, 32801<br />
<span>Phone: <a href="tel:5555555555">(555) 555-8899</a></span></address>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 ct-u-paddingTop10">
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="app store" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/appstore.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 ct-u-paddingTop10">
          <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="google play store" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/androidstore.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <ul class="ct-socials list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li>
              <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="facebook" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/facebook-white.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="twitter" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/twitter-white.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="youtube" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/youtube-white.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="instagram" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/instagram-white.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="pinterest" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/pinterest-white.png" /></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ct-footer-post">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="inner-left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-right">
        <p>Copyright © 2016 WebCorpCo.&nbsp;<a href="">Privacy Policy</a></p>

        <p><a class="ct-u-motive-color" href="" target="_blank">Web Design</a> by DigitalUs on <a href="" target="_blank">Solodev CMS</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I haved checked your code very well there is nothing overlapping anything i just copied the whole container above your footer and everything seems fine can you please say what are you facing because its not clear your code is pretty good

Comment: Alright no problem currently when I apply the code to a block which is the footer block it would black out the entire website. I also have a site map block right above the footer block but I don't think that's the issue. I've tried another footer it's solves the issue but it's not a responsive footer and faces distortion when I check the mobile version.  I'll attach the code I have for non responsive footer.

Comment: as i test it its totally responsive and its fine maybe you can upload your code in github page or jsfiddle you can try to provide full code maybe there is something missing which you don't have it in this snippet that you have it in your post

Comment: Ok, The problem is my old footer works fine and doesn't have this overlapping issue only, just not being mobile friendly. here's the link to the old footer.  https://github.com/userinz/drupalsite/commit/9aabc36374b59314de553bb1784c48539d421b00?diff=unified. It's quite strange, since I thought the new one was my fault. I'll just post the new one again and see if it's something I've missed.

Comment: Alright here's the new footer this one is a responsive footer from the old footer. I've checked this one and still have the overlapping issues on the Drupal website. https://gist.github.com/userinz/0e5bcf834d02b4a2bb3df614531a9b5c

Comment: I really have no clue now what the problem is here i took all your code from github and i put it in jsfiddle i copied the container 2 times to see what's wrong and nothing wrong man  https://jsfiddle.net/am987rff/4/  please sees like you cant figure out what do you want

Comment: @AdelElkhodary Ok it's look fines on the preview mode on drupal but when I publish it on the site it just overlaps everything.My old footer doesn't have this issue just the new footer. I'll attach an image on what happens since the snippet shows the div closing the footer correctly, but isn't the case on drupal.

Comment: @AdelElkhodary I figured it out! I put a <span </span> and <br> at the begining of the code. The footer stays in place and doesn't overlap on the drupal site any more, just need to adjust the size of footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure I did to make the footer stay in place and not overlap the content is putting  a  and 
  I even added a

---

to double check the issue, at the beginning of the code. The footer stays in place and doesn't overlap the website content anymore. It's also a very responsive footer plus the improvement.

```
<style type="text/css">html,
body,
img,
figure {
  max-width: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #000;
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
a {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.ct-u-paddingTop10 {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.ct-footer {
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.ct-footer-pre {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.ct-footer-pre span {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ct-footer-pre .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
.ct-footer-pre .form-group:before,
.ct-footer-pre .form-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.ct-footer-pre .form-group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
  border: 1px solid #39a2bf;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0
}
.ct-footer-list {
  padding: 50px 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.ct-footer-list > li .ct-footer-list-header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #3a98b2;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ct-footer-list > li ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.ct-footer-list > li ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.ct-footer-list > li ul li a:hover,
.ct-footer-post a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ct-footer-post {
  background: #000;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.ct-footer-post .inner-left,
.ct-footer-post .inner-right {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.ct-footer-post ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}
.ct-footer-post ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.ct-footer-post a {
  color: #fff;
}
.ct-footer-post p {
  color: #fff;
}
.ct-footer-meta {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.ct-footer-meta .ct-socials {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.ct-footer-meta .ct-socials li {
  padding: 0 3px;
}
.ct-footer--with-button {
  padding-top: 150px;
}
address {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
address span {
  font-weight: 600;
}
address a {
  color: #fff;
}
address a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #111;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 12px 30px;
}
.btn.btn-motive {
  background-color: #00bff3;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.btn.btn-motive:hover,
.btn.btn-motive:hover:active {
  background-color: #00bff3;
}
.btn.btn-violet {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4f4f99;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.btn.btn-violet:hover {
  background-color: #37376b;
}
.btn.btn-violet:hover:active {
  background-color: #2f2f5b
}
.btn.btn-green {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #43670f;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.btn.btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #36520c;
}
.btn.btn-green:hover:active {
  background-color: #314a0b;
}
.btn.btn-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da2229;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.btn.btn-red:hover {
  background-color: #ae1b21;
}
.btn.btn-red:hover:active {
  background-color: #9d181e
}
.btn.btn-white {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.btn.btn-white:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.btn.btn-white:hover:active {
  background-color: #c9c9c9
}

.btn.btn-large {
  padding: 20px 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: normal;
}
.ct-mediaSection {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.ct-section_header--type1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 115px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.ct-section_header--type2 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 58px;
  line-height: .7;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  left: -12px;
}
.ct-section_header--type2 span {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 115px;
  line-height: .8;
}
.ct-section_header--type2 img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
.ct-section_header--type3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.ct-section_header--type3 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("/core/fileparse.php/16/urlt/../images/ribbon.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: block
}
.ct-section_header--type3 span {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  font-size: 150px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: .85
}
.ct-section_header--type4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.ct-section_header--type4:before,
.ct-section_header--type4:after {
  content: '';
  display: table
}
.ct-section_header--type4:after {
  clear: both
}
.ct-section_header--type4 small {
  font-family: 'coquette', fantasy;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block
}
.ct-section_header--type4 span {
  font-family: 'nimbus-sans-condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  line-height: .7
}
.ct-section_header + p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ct-section_header--type4 + p {
  font-family: 'nimbus-sans-condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
}

/* Media Queries */

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .ct-footer-pre {
    display: table;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre > .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .ct-footer-list > li {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .ct-footer-list > li:last-child {
    width: 7%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1199px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group {
      padding-top: 15px
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .ct-footer-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
  .ct-footer-post .inner-left {
    float: left;
  }
  .ct-footer-post .inner-right {
    float: right;
  }
}
@media (max-width:991px) {
  .ct-footer-post {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .ct-footer-list > li {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .ct-footer-post p {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .ct-footer-post p + p {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  address {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:767px) {
  .ct-footer-list > li {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width:480px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
    top: -1px;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
    width: 331px;
  }
}
@media (max-width:479px) {
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group input {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .ct-footer-pre .form-group button {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .ct-footer-list > li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .ct-footer-list {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .btn.btn-large {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    line-height: .9;
    font-size: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -.2px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: .8;
  }
  .ct-section_header + p {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type3 small {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4 small {
      font-size: 40px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type3 span {
    font-size: 90px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4 span {
      font-size: 80px;
  }
  .ct-section_header--type4 + p {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="container">&nbsp;</div>

<footer class="ct-footer">
<div class="container">
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="contentForm">&nbsp;</form>

<ul class="ct-footer-list text-center-sm">
    <li>
    <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Contract Vechciles</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Services</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sales</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Programming</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">About us</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Thought Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Webinars</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sponsorships</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Advisors</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Training Program</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Activities &amp; Campaigns</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <h2 class="ct-footer-list-header">Resources&nbsp;</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">WebCorpCo Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hackathons</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Newsletters</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Board</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="ct-footer-meta text-center-sm">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img alt="logo" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/logo.png" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<address><span>WebCorpCo</span><br />
123 Easy Street<br />
Orlando, Florida, 32801<br />
<span>Phone: <a href="tel:5555555555">(555) 555-8899</a></span></address>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 ct-u-paddingTop10">&nbsp;<a href="" target="_blank">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<p><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="facebook" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/facebook-white.png" /></a><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="twitter" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/twitter-white.png" /></a><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="youtube" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/youtube-white.png" /></a><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="instagram" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/instagram-white.png" /></a><a href="" target="_blank"><img alt="pinterest" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/footer/pinterest-white.png" /></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ct-footer-post">
<div class="container">
<div class="inner-left">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="inner-right">
<p>Copyright © 2016 WebCorpCo.&nbsp;<a href="">Privacy Policy</a></p>

<p><a class="ct-u-motive-color" href="" target="_blank">Web Design</a> by DigitalUs on <a href="" target="_blank">Solodev CMS</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```